# C++ : How to read text file in chunks and run functions on each chunk?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, file, memory

I want to read a text file from local storage, I'm trying to experiment with multiprocessing so I want to break the text file into smaller chunks and run a process on them.

**Rough idea**:

Input: 10Kb text file

Program to separate them into chunks of 1Kb each

Run a function on each chunk separately (Eg: Capitalise certain characters, find the frequency of letters or search for a word in that chunk)

Output: Return the function output with no memory leaks or mismatches in reads

I've tried using `pread` but I'm on windows, so any solution or leads to solve this would be helpful

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have an [mre] of your attempt? What problems do you have with your attempt?

Comment: In C++ for reading files, you can use `std::ifstream`.

Comment: Also note that variable-length files (like text-files) are generally not well-handled in static "chunks". You can't tell if a "chunk" splits on words, sentences or whatever separates records in the file. What are you supposed to do with the file and its contens?

Comment: This is my progress so far, I'm not sure about the third file one as I found it on some thread online. [codeshare](https://codeshare.io/78pPDo)

I want to merge the first and second file logic to break text file chunks and run a function on them

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please don't forget how to [edit] your questions, for example to include your [mre] copy-pasted as text together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have chosen the wrong example to learn multithreading.

A file stored on a sequential drive will be read fastest in sequential mode.

Therefore I will read, in my example below, the complete file in one rush into a string. For test purposes I used a "Lorem Ipsum" generator and created a file with 1 million characters. 1 million is nowadays considered as still small.

For demo purposes, I will create 4 parallel threads.

After having this complete file in one string, I will split the big string into 4 substrings. One for each thread.

For the thread function, I created a 4 liner test function that calculates the count of letters for a given substring.

For easier learning, I will use `std::async` to create the threads. The result of `std::async` will be stored in a `std::future`. There we can pick up the test function result later. We need to used a `shared_future` to be able to store all of them in an a `std::array`, because the `std::future`'s copy constructor is deleted.

Then, we let the threads do their work.

In an additional loop, we use the futures `get`function, which will wait for thread completion and then give us the result.

We sum up the values from all 4 threads and then print it out in a sorted way. Please note: Also the `\n`will be counted, which will look a little bit strange in the output.

Please note. This is just demoe. It will be even slower than a straight forwad solution. It is just for showing hwo multithreading could work.

Please see below one simple example (one of many many possible solutions):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iterator>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <array>
#include <set>
// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Create aliases. Save typing work and make code more readable
using Pair = std::pair<char, unsigned int>;

// Standard approach for counter
using Counter = std::unordered_map<Pair::first_type, Pair::second_type>;

// Sorted values will be stored in a multiset
struct Comp { bool operator ()(const Pair& p1, const Pair& p2) const { return (p1.second == p2.second) ? p1.first<p2.first : p1.second>p2.second; } };
using Rank = std::multiset<Pair, Comp>;
// ------------------------------------------------------------

// We will use 4 threads for our task
constexpr size_t NumberOfThreads = 4u;

// Some test function used by a thread. Count characters in text
Counter countCharacters(const std::string& text) {

    // Definition of the counter
    Counter counter{};

    // Count all letters
    for (const char c : text) counter[c]++;

    // Give back result
    return counter;
}

// Test / driver Code
int main() {
    // Open a test file with 1M characters and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream sourceStream{ "r:\\text.txt" }; sourceStream) {

        // Read the complete 1M file into a string
        std::string text(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceStream), {});
        

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // This is for the multhreading part
        
        // We will split the big string in parts and give each thread the task to work with this part
        // Calculate the length of one partition + some reserve in case of rounding problem
        const size_t partLength = text.length() / NumberOfThreads + NumberOfThreads;
        
        // We will create numberOfThread Substrings starting at equidistant positions. This is the start.
        size_t threadStringStartpos = 0;

        // Container for the futures. Please note. We can only use shared futures in containers.
        std::array<std::shared_future<Counter>, NumberOfThreads> counter{};

        // Now create the threats
        for (unsigned int threadNumber{}; threadNumber < NumberOfThreads; ++threadNumber) {
        
            // STart a thread. Get a reference to the future. And call it with our test function and a part of the string
            counter[threadNumber] = std::async( countCharacters, text.substr(threadStringStartpos, partLength));

            // Calculate next part of string
            threadStringStartpos += partLength;
        }
        // Combine results from threads
        Counter result{};
        for (unsigned int threadNumber{}; threadNumber < NumberOfThreads; ++threadNumber) {

            // Get will get the result from the thread via the assigned future
            for (const auto& [letter, count] : counter[threadNumber].get())
                result[letter] += count;    // Sum up all counts
        }
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        for (const auto& [letter, count] : Rank(result.begin(), result.end())) std::cout << letter << " --> " << count << '\n';
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open source file\n";
}
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution but I think there's a lot of time wasted in reading the entire file to a string. Is there a way it's read character by character directly from the file? That would increase the performance by a lot.